# MEF and WPF custom import definition

Tags: wpf, mef

I have this idea to try to use a custom IMPORT attribute to new up a class based on a condition. For example, if I have:

[Import("Position_32")] this should exist if I'm running a 32bit OS, and then:

[Import("Position_64")] if Im running a 64 bit OS. Is there any way to make the type name for the attribute dynamic based on a condition?

Conceptually it could look like this:

[Import(((IsWIN64()) ? "Position_64" : "Position_32"))]  This doesn't work because the type name needs to be a constant.

I want to make the newing up of the proper position class as transparent as possible. I mean I did a factory based method using funcs to get my desired effect but I'd love to use MEF for this. Ideas?

THanks much,

David

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ExportMetadataAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.exportmetadataattribute.aspx) like so:

```
[Import("Position")]
[ExportMetadata("Platform", "32bit")]
public YourType ...
```

Then, when you go to import, use:

```
 [ImportMany]
 public Lazy<YourType,IDictionary<string,object>>[] Positions { get; set; }
```

You can then check the `Dictionary` for the appropriate metadata, and use that specific platform, at runtime.

In addition, you can make a custom interface for strongly typed metadata (instead of strings).  For details, see [Exports and Metadata](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata).

Comment: Nice. Ill have a look at these. Thanks so much